# Facebook API: friend is writing a message?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-chat

I'd like to know if there's a way, in any language, to know when a friend is writing a message through Facebook API or others.

My target is to build ssomething to be notified when a friend is writing me a message (as it works on snapchat). If there's already a way/an app to have this please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: There is no such endpoint

Comment: It is only possible for Facebook Messenger via the [XEP-0085](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html) protocol extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend permissions are gone and the Chat API is deprecated, there is no way to do this with any language.